# Retrieving IPP access token and access secret from paypal callback

Tags: paypal, oauth, intuit-partner-platform

I have a web app that uses a standard paypal shopping cart.  What we want to do is to automatically record payments in QB online using Intuit QB API when paypal notifies our web site that the payment has completed.

The examples I have seen for obtaining the access token and secret are user-initiated.  How can I get these inside the context of this paypal callback?  I need them to happen automatically, and without a Request context from a user.  I have some basic test code here that runs within the paypal callback.

```
//start a transaction
//start try block            
//set our transaction record as paid
Token = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["appToken"];
        string consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerKey"];
        string consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["consumerSecret"];
        string companyID = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["companyID"];
        string accessToken = "??????";
        string accessSecret = "?????";

        OAuthRequestValidator oauthValidator = new OAuthRequestValidator(accessToken, accessSecret, consumerKey, consumerSecret);
        ServiceContext context = new ServiceContext(appToken, companyID, IntuitServicesType.QBO, oauthValidator);
        DataService service = new DataService(context);
        Customer customer = new Customer();
        //just a test example. without missing tokens, i don't get here.
        customer.GivenName = "Mary";
        customer.Title = "Ms.";
        customer.MiddleName = "Jayne";
        customer.FamilyName = "Cooper";
        Customer resultCustomer = service.Add(customer) as Customer;
//complete transaction
//catch {rollback transaction}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no automated way to get access tokens and secret from your application.
You need to generate them for the first time using user interaction(C2QB- Connect to Quickbooks) and then save them for future use. These tokens are valid for a period of 6 months after which you will have to call Reconnect api to renew the tokens or do a C2QB interaction again to get new tokens.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0030_integrate_your_app/disconnecting_from_quickbooks/0050_how_to_reconnect